# Lucene Difference between term and query?

Tags: lucene

What is the exact difference between the Term based index and the Query based Index also searching in LUCENE 6.5?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know where you heard about "term-based" and "query-based" indexes.

- Terms are the analyzed chunks of the text in the index. Most commonly, these are words, but it depends on your analyzer.
- Queries are a set of search criteria that specifies what to look for among the indexed terms.